# single JSONProperty name assigned to 2 properties

Tags: c#, json.net, json-deserialization

Let say you want to store the JSON object as a Dictionary but also as your own custom object.
Problem is when you Deserialize the JSON object you can't assign the same JSONProperty to 2 different properties in the same class.

`{foo: {bar: "do", bar2:"doo"}}`

```
[JSONProperty("foo")]
public Dictionary<string,object>RawJSON{get; set;}

[JSONProperty("foo")]
public CustomClass FooClass{get;set;}
```

This will not work as the Newtonsoft deserialize will not allow the same JSON to be applied to multiple properties. I had thought about modifing the setter but of course you can assign a dictionary to a custom Class

```
        [JsonProperty("foo")]
        public Dictionary<string, object> RawJSON{
            get { return RawJSON; }
            set {
                RawJSON = value;
                FooClass= value;
            }
        }

        public CustomClass FooClass{get;set;}
```

Comment: What is your question?  If Custom  class is not dictionary your code will not be even compiled. Why are you posting it? even without testing.

Comment: Is that first piece of text `{foo: {bar: ...` supposed to be **JSON data**? If it is, then it is missing 5 double quotes: two property names are completely unquoted, and one is half quoted. If it isn't meant to be JSON data, then what is it meant to be? Furthermore it would help if CustomClass was included (at least as an example that matches the input data).

Comment: @Serge No CustomClass is not a Dictionary. I post that code as an example of what would not work as to stop people from posting that as an answer